# Add shapes during runtime from another class in Javafx

Tags: java, scala, javafx, javafx-8

I have a simple JavaFX program in Scala where I have a Pane that I write shapes in.

```
class SimpleWindow extends Application {
  val pane = new BorderPane
  val subPane = new Pane
  var coord = (0, 0)
  var primeStage: Stage = _
  var x = 600
  var y = 600

  override def start(primaryStage: Stage) {
    primeStage = primaryStage
    pane.setCenter(subPane)
    val line = new Line(25, 25, 50, 50)
    subPane.getChildren.add(line)

    val x = 600
    val y = 600
    val scene = new Scene(pane, x, y)

    // Finalize and show the stage
    primaryStage.setScene(scene)
    primaryStage.setTitle("The Click Me App")
    primaryStage.show()
  }

  def moveTo(x: Int, y: Int): Unit = {
    SimpleWindow.this.coord = (x, y)
  }

  def lineTo(x: Int, y: Int): Unit = {
    val line = new Line(coord._1, coord._2, x, y)
    SimpleWindow.this.subPane.getChildren.add(line)
    SimpleWindow.this.coord = (x, y)
  }
}
```

Now the simplewindow class is going to be on a separate thread, and I want to be able to make a new line from an outside class using the lineTo method. This is where it all fails, when I use the lineTo from the other class (on a separate thread) the gui does not update, and I believe I need some sort of listener on the pane for it to update when a node gets added but I do not know how.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaFX as in most other GUI frameworks you have to access UI controls only from the dedicated "UI-thread". If you want to communicate some information from a background thread, you should use [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) call which posts work to that thread.

You may also consider reading [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) tutorial about some higher level API.

Comment: I did wrap my lineTo method in a Platform.runLater but it did not help at all. But I'll try to look more into a soltion using that, thanks.

Comment: @Superovan, `runLater` should help. If it doesn't, we need a reproducible example where it results in an exception (or wrong behavior) anyway.